# loading .jtl file does not give complete result in gui, can not see response data

Tags: jmeter

I am running Jmeter in non-gui mode. When I load the resulting.jtl file in jmeter I can see sample result but it does not give me sampler request and response data. Help appreciated!

Answer (score 8):

By default sampler request and response data are not stored in the .jtl file. To override this behavior you need to "tell" JMeter to store the data. To do so locate the following properties in *jmeter.properties* file which lives under /bin folder of your JMeter installation, uncomment and change to "true" values of the following:

```
#jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=false
```

Alternatively you can pass these properties during command-line execution via -J key as follows:

```
jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true -n -t /path/to/your/script.jmx -l /path/to/results/file.jtl
```

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](http://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information on dealing with JMeter properties.

Also be aware of the fact that storing requests and especially responses will have negative impact on your load generator(s) performance.

Comment: I have set to "true" values indicated above, but when I open JTL file I still cannot see response data. If I edit the JTL file using command, I am able to see response. But if I open the file in GUI, response data tab do not display response and "show text" , "render html" radio buttons are disabled.

Comment: @Dmitri If we want to save the request data into the jtl file in such case what is to  be done

Comment: Above answer should be enough. For storing request and response data you will need to switch JMeter results file to .xml format via `jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml` property